# Accepted a PhD offer but no reply

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I got accepted to a PhD program in England. I received a formal offer letter on January 20th, which stated that I was supposed to contact the Graduate Studies Administrator via email in order to accept the offer. So I sent them an email on January 24th, telling them that I intended to accept it. However, I have not yet received their reply, and I am wondering if my email was properly delivered to them. According to the letter, the deadline to accept the offer is February 14th. Should I send them a follow-up email?

Comment: Check your spam filter (in case you haven't already done so)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**.

It's only been four days. In fact it's been less than four days, since 24 Jan to 27 Jan includes a weekend.

Be patient and they'll get back to you in time.